# Update User Info with restful_authentication plugin in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-plugins, restful-authentication

I want to give the users the ability to change their account info with restful_authentication plugin in rails.

I added this two methods to my users controller:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      # Only update password when necessary
      params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?

      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
          format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
          format.xml  { head :ok }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "edit" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

Also, I copied **new.html.erb** to **edit.html.erb**. Considering that resources are already defined in routes.rb I was expecting it to work easily, but somehow when I click the save button it calls the **create** method, instead of **update**, using a **POST HTTP request**.
Immediately after that it automatically **logs out** from the session.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably, if you showed your `edit.html.erb`, it would help to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be possible that the selected user could not be found in your `edit` method?
Then `@user` is empty and your form thinks that you are creating a new user.

Try to add debugging output in the `edit` method, like this:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  logger.debug "Found user = #{@user.inspect}"
end
```

And check if your log messages shows that the user is found or not.